# How can I make this flash video not automatically play on display?

Tags: javascript, flash, autoplay, flash-video

I'm using javascript to display a flash video but it always plays automatically. How can I tell it to just display?

```
                                    AC_FL_RunContent(
                                        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,45,0',
                                            'width', '550',
                                            'height', '400',
                                            'src', 'Clip',
                                            'id', 'Clip',
                                            'name', 'Clip',
                                            'movie', 'Clip',
                                            'quality', 'high',
                                            'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                                            'align', 'middle',
                                            'play', 'false',
                                            'loop', 'true',
                                            'scale', 'showall',
                                            'wmode', 'window',
                                            'devicefont', 'false',
                                            'bgcolor', '#000000',
                                            'menu', 'true',
                                            'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                                            'allowFullScreen','true',
                                            'autostart', 'false',
                                            'salign', '' ); 
                                    //end AC code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'autoPlay' instead of 'autostart'

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the value of the loop parameter to false as well. That works for me.